# Write and read object to and from file

Tags: java, object, save

I want to read and write an object to a file. This is my attempt:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SaveOpen implements Serializable 
{
    private static String fileName;
    private ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public SaveOpen() {
        fileName = "file.txt";
    }
    //Reader
    public static Object deserialize() throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Object obj = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return obj; 
    }
    //Writer
    public static void serialize(Object obj)
            throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.close();
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public ArrayList<Person> getListPersons() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

However, I do not know if this is the correct way nor how to implement this in a class. The object is `Person` and I want to save and read that object from a file. Is it supposed to be done to a `.txt` file? Anyone who can clearify things? Thanks!

Comment: If you're serializing an object using a stream, then you're writing binary data, not text, so you should not write to a `.txt` file.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing it to a `.txt` file, however that suggests that the contents are text, which they're not.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/ <= There are examples available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the file to be human readable i would suggest to save it as xml.

Example :

- Object Class

  ```
  import java.io.Serializable;

  public class Person implements Serializable
  {
       private String username;
       private int    id;

       public String UserName() { return username; }
       public void setUserName(String str) { username = str;} 

       public int ID() { return id; }
       public void setID(int ID) { id = ID; }    
  }
  ```

-Serializer/Deserializer

```
import Settings.Person;
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class XmlSerializer 
{
    //File path to serialize to and deserialize from
    private static final String SERIALIZED_FILE_NAME = "yourSavePath.xml";
    //Insert person object and save as xml file to chosen filepath
    public static void Serialize(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream    os = new FileOutputStream(SERIALIZED_FILE_NAME);
            XMLEncoder          encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
                                encoder.writeObject(person);
                                encoder.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    //Deserialize xml file into person object
    public static Person Deserialize()
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream os = new FileInputStream(SERIALIZED_FILE_NAME);
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(os);
            Person p = (Person)decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
            return p;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right already. You can safe Objects in a txt file altough it makes not much sense, I'd rather go with a binary file.

To store multiple Objects in a single File, simply pack them in a Collection and then serialize the Collection object.

When reading an Object from a File, check its Class via instanceof and cast it to whatever it is.